# I am not being able to use yii console commands in yii 2.0.16 version

Tags: yii2, console, yii2-advanced-app

I have started using yii 2.0.16 version. When I made migration command in order to create initial user table, it didn't work. Instead, it showed view like this:
[image]

Can you help, please

Comment: What command you're using?

Comment: ```yii migrate``` in order to initialize migration and user tables

Comment: In any yii command it shows that info

Comment: I hope you have followed all necessary steps from [Yii2 installation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation). I will suggest you should install it using composer. Have you created Database ..?

Comment: I did all steps properly. I've created db and connected it

Comment: do you have the project setup on GIT? can you show it.

Comment: It's in my local server on my laptop